# near "": syntax error in SQL with android studio

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I'm working on a SQL databse on java (android studio project) but i have a weird mistake.
Basically, everytime i have

```
near "Hello": syntax error in "INSERT INTO GAMES(_id, PRICE, NAME, DEV, PLATFORM) VALUES (0, 70, Hello, Henri, Terrain)"
```

I have tried like this

```
public void addGame(String Price, String Name, String Dev, String Platform) {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ SchemeDB.TAB_GAMES +"("
            + DBS.COL_GAMES_ID +", "
            + DBS.COL_GAMES_PRICE +", "
            + DBS.COL_GAMES_NAME +", "
            + DBS.COL_GAMES_DEV +", "
            + DBS.COL_GAMES_PLATFORM +") VALUES (" + i +", "
            + Price +", "
            + Name +", "
            + Dev +", "
            + Platform +")");
    database.close();

}
```

My DBS is

```
public interface SchemeDB {

    int VERSION = 1;
    String DB_NAME = "????";
    String TAB_GAMES = "???";
    String COL_GAMES_ID = "_id";
    String COL_GAMES_PRICE = "PRICE";
    String COL_GAMES_NAME = "NAME";
    String COL_GAMES_DEV = "DEV";
    String COL_GAMES_PLATFORM = "PLATFORM";

}
```

And i really don't see where is the mistake. Because they're saying "syntax error", but for me, it's look pretty OKAY.
Anyone have a clue ? I'm just trying to insert some things in my Database.

Comment: You missed scape the quotes for `NAME` column

Comment: @James Sorry but can you tell me the line ? I'm looking but i don't see nothing

Comment: This should be `INSERT INTO GAMES(_id, PRICE, NAME, DEV, PLATFORM) VALUES (0, 70, 'Hello', 'Henri', 'Terrain')` to work. You are just concatenating strings, so you need to add the extra `'`.

Comment: Even better, use prepared statements so you don't have to think about quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
    + "'" + Name + "', "
    + "'" + Dev  + "', "
    + "'" + Platform + "')");
```